# FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RegIntentService] after upgrading to com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Macbook Pro, Android Studio 2.2. I have the latest SDK. Today, I upgraded the dependencies of my app as below (support libraries used to be version 23):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

No change in minSDK (15), but targetSDK is 25 to match the support libraries. I cleaned the project and rebuilt. Then loaded it to an android 4.1.1 device via usb. This used to be working but, after the changes it`s been crashing on startup with the following stack trace:

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=24: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42075468)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RegIntentService]
                  java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>:(Ljava/lang/String;)V from class com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                      at com.moapy.eyeniaras.satdostum.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:54)
                      at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

RegistrationIntentService.java:54 has:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
```

Debugging it, I realized that without this line the app starts but as soon as passing that point it stops. Tried to solve the issue but was not able to find a solution, googled the issue but could not anything useful.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0` is fairly old, and I will not be surprised if it does not work with `25.0.1` of the support libraries. If you want to use `25.0.1`, move to a newer `play-services` (e.g., `10.0.0`). Also, unless you are using every single Play Services API, you might consider using a more granular dependency than `play-services`, to speed up your builds and reduce the size of your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I updated to compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'. Cleaned, Rebuilt, Invalidated cache, Restarted. Now getting: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0. I searched the text 8.3.0 but it exists only in cache.xml. Nowhere else I use 8.3.0, why the conflict?

Comment: Well, Play Services has changed over the years, and certain APIs now work with a plugin. Personally, I haven't used those. This goes back to my earlier recommendation: get rid of `play-services` and replace it with specific dependencies for the specific APIs that you are using (e.g., `play-services-maps`). If you are lucky, the ones that you are using do not need this plugin. Otherwise, add the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Update Google Play Services to the latest version and android support library to latest version. 9.8 for google play services and 25.0.1 for the android support libraries seems to make it work.